# Using solve command for specific pair of equations in Maple produces no result, but a simple algebraic change produces a result, why?

Tags: maple

Say I have the following two equations:

$$2000 = k \ln {\frac{t+1}{t}}$$
$$2000 = k \ln {\frac{t+3}{t+1}}$$

The solution for $t$ is $t=1$, which is easily obtained equating the two equations and exponentiating both sides.

In Maple, this is:

```
e1 := 2000 = k*ln((t + 1)/t)
e2 := 2000 = k*ln((t + 3)/(t + 1))
solve({ e1, e2 }, { t })
```

The $solve$ command produces no result above. If instead I do

```
e3 := k*ln((t + 1)/t) = k*ln((t + 3)/(t + 1))
solve(e3, t)
```

I obtain the correct answer $t=1$.

**Why doesn't the solve command work when $e1$ and $e2$ are considered a system of two equations?**

Comment: In the first piece of code, why is `t` in curly braces?

Comment: In the first system you are explicity setting `e1` and `e2` to $2000$, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: The curly braces are because that is the syntax I saw in the book I am following, "Understanding Maple" by Ian Thompson.

Comment: Maple programming questions such as this (which are not primarily about mathematics) are off-topic for this forum. More appropriate are forums  www.mapleprimes.com  or  stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e1 := 2000 = k*ln((t + 1)/t)
e2 := 2000 = k*ln((t + 3)/(t + 1))
solve({ e1, e2 }, { t , k})
```

works fine, and returns the solution.  You asked for maple to solve the system for `t` but to keep `k` arbitrary -- there is indeed no solution then.